# Cat files in subfolders in order given by a list

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a folder x with a number of sufolders ale, bae, galo and inside each subfolder one .pest file.

```
x/ale/ale.pest 
x/bae/bae.pest 
x/galo/galo.pest
```

I have a list in folder y containing the order I should cat .pest files

```
bae
galo
ale
```

from my x folder I'm trying

```
for file in ./*/*.pest; do while read line; do cat "$line".pest; done; done  <./y/list
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the follow-up subtly different question:

> I'm still wondering how would be if my subdirectories didn't have same names as in list though....

Let's make some assumptions:

- All the subdirectories of `x` are fair game.
- All `.pest` files are fair game.
- If you have two `.pest` files with the same name (but in different directories), you don't care what order those two files will be `cat`ed in.

Then you have:

```
while read -r name; do
    cat x/*/"$name.pest"
done <y/list >concatenated.pest
```

Adding sanity checking is a little bit trickier but still doable.  (I'm not doing that part as I don't know if my assumptions even match your use case.)

Answer (score 7):

You have the order in a list, so don't match the filenames with a filename globbing pattern.  Instead, construct the names from the strings read from the list:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r name; do
    cat "x/$name/$name.pest"
done <y/list >concatenated.pest
```

This would concatenate all the relevant `.pest` files and create a single file called `concatenated.pest` from these in the current directory, in the order read from `y/list`.

With a bit of checking included:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r name; do
    pathname="x/$name/$name.pest"

    if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then
        printf 'Can not find %s\n' "$pathname"
        echo 'Output file will be incomplete'
        exit 1
    fi >&2

    cat "$pathname"
done <y/list >concatenated.pest
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm still wondering how would be if my subdirectories didnt have same names as in list though...

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens In this question, the _do_ all have the same names as the actual `.pest` file. If they don't, then maybe they follow some other pattern that would be easily handled. If not, you may want to ask a separate question about that, but I doubt it would be too difficult.

Comment: got it! k I'll post as a different question bc I'm also having to process some files like that. thxs

Comment: I posted a modified version of the answer to illustrate the easiest way to handle differently named subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

Since you can supply multiple files to `cat` it would be nice to only start one instance after some path name mangling:

```sh
sed 's|.*|x/&/&.pest|' < y/filename-list.txt | xargs -d '\n' cat
```

Explanation:

- `sed 's|A|B|'` replaces all occurrences of `A` with `B`.

  - Here A is `.*` which matches any character sequence regardless of length or content.
  - `&` in B is a placeholder for the entire text matched with A.
- `xargs [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [ARGS...]` runs `COMMAND [ARGS...]` after appending the tokens on its standard input stream to the command.

  - Normally tokens are delimited by any amount of white-space character. Using `-d` tells `xargs` to use a different delimiter, in this case `\n`, the newline character.
  - If your `xargs` installation doesn’t support `-d`, you need to make sure that the input tokens don’t contain white-space. On Linux, typically you’ll have GNU `xargs` which does support `-d`.